# A basic problem on distribution function

Tags: probability-theory

Let $F$ and $G$ be two distribution functions. Given that the largest square that can be inscribed between $F$ and $G$ has less than $\epsilon$ length I want to prove that for any $x$ there exist $x_0$ and $y_0$, $|x_0-y_0| \leq \epsilon$ such that $$ \epsilon + F(x_0) - F(y_0) \geq |F(x) - G(x)|$$.

I tried to draw a square of length $ \epsilon$ from the point $(x, F(x))$ to the left side then that will cross $G$ surely. Is it true that the length below the square is higher than the length above it i.e. $|F(x) -G(x)| -\epsilon < F(x) - F(x-\epsilon)$. I don't think so.